# Optimizing checklist for a lot of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a checklist for ~1500 items

here's currently how I do it

```js
  toggleOpenTimeSlot = (timeSlotId) => {
    if (this.isTimeSlotOpened(timeSlotId)) {
      this.setState({
        openedTimeSlots: this.state.openedTimeSlots.filter(
          (id) => id !== timeSlotId
        ),
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        openedTimeSlots: [...this.state.openedTimeSlots, timeSlotId],
      });
    }
  };

  isTimeSlotOpened = (timeSlotId) =>
    this.state.openedTimeSlots.includes(timeSlotId);
```

But this approach is very slow, every time I check a checkbox, it takes more than a second to rerender

I also tried something like this

```js
 toggleOpenTimeSlot = (timeSlotId) => {
    if (this.isTimeSlotOpened(timeSlotId)) {
      this.setState((state) => {
        return {
          ...state,
          openedTimeSlots: {
            ...state.openedTimeSlots,
            [timeSlotId.toString()]: false,
          },
        };
      });
    } else {
      this.setState((state) => {
        const newOpenedTimeSlots = { ...state.openedTimeSlots };
        delete newOpenedTimeSlots[timeSlotId.toString()];

        return {
          ...state,
          openedTimeSlots: newOpenedTimeSlots,
        };
      });
    }
  };

  isTimeSlotOpened = (timeSlotId) =>
    this.state.openedTimeSlots[timeSlotId.toString()];
```

But it seems the performance gets worse after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to render it step by step!

Trying to display all the checkboxes at once, is bad practice code.

So, if your user should scroll to see the other check boxes ! you need to just show them just 10 or 20 of them and check if user is at the end of the scroll view, load next 20 checkboxes.

By using this such technique your program will never gets slow.

Comment: Can I still use the same method for checking if the checkbox is checked? I havent tried but I don't know if using react-virtualized will instantly solve my problem, I'll give it a try though

Comment: I think you can, try it.

Comment: Yeah it turns out the biggest cause for the performance issue is that it needs to render a lot of checkboxes at once. I'm using react-virtuoso while still using the old checking method, and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Make openTimeSlots as Object instead of an Array and use timeSlotId as key and value of that should be true/false.

```
toggleOpenTimeSlot = (timeSlotId) => {
  this.setState({
    openedTimeSlots: {...this.state.openedTimeSlots, [timeSlotId]: !this.state.openedTimeSlots[timeSlotId]
  });};
```

Comment: Yes I did try something like this as I explained in the post, but it doesnt seem to make things better. Im currently trying to virtualize the list and see if that can fix the problem immediately

Comment: deleting the property from an object will affect the performance sometimes.